# Import and further development of a Bootstrap 3.2.0 template in ASP .NET MVC 5 project @ Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2013, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a new ASP .NET MVC 5 project in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. I chose some Bootstrap template (based on 3.2.0 version) on the internet, which I want to use in my project. I purchased the license for using that template and downloaded the appropriate package with sources, docs and so on.
There is several sections inside this package:

- dist - production files (merged .html files, .css merged into 1 files, .js merged into 2 files, etc.)
- dev - development files (divided into several layouts .html files, divided .less, divided .js and so on)
- docs - documentation

Because I am not very experienced web developer, I feel a lack of information inside on how to import this template into my project and how to continue the further development using this template in a good way.

There is a development setup guide section:

> To work with the included development files you need to install the
> following: You need to install Node.js, Bower, Grunt, Jekyll.
>
> After Node is Installed open command line/terminal and go to your app
> folder inside the dev folder:

```
npm install
// Will install all packages set in dev/package.json
// Important! On windows you need to create the npm/ folder as for the path shown in the error

bower install
// Will install bower components set in dev/bower.json
// Important! On windows you need to install msysgit.github.io and add it to your environment path this is for having access to bower in the command line.
```

> To generate production files (demo) run:

```
grunt
// Will compile all assets and create the dist/dev at the same level(outside) of /dev
```

> To compile less files without processing HTML with Jekyll run:

```
grunt less
```

**And, finally, the questions:**

1. What are these technologies/tools (**Node.js, Bower, Grunt, Jekyll**) used for, how they are connected between each other?
2. What are the tools/extensions for development inside **Visual Studio 2013**, which will help to import development sources of chosen Bootstrap template (**Node.js, Bower, Grunt, Jekyll** as said in the development setup guide) into **ASP .NET MVC 5** project and to continue further development?
3. What are the ways/guidelines/patterns/practices about how to import and continue further development of a Bootstrap template in **ASP. NET MVC 5** project inside **Visual Studio 2013**?

Comment: Question 1: It's primarily opinion based.   Question 2: It's also primarily opinion based.  Question 3: Is to broad, SO is designed to answer specific programming questions.

Comment: "What are these technologies/tools (Node.js, Bower, Grunt, Jekyll) used for" Try using Google.

Answer (score 2):

1: This is a pretty loaded technical question, and probably deserves it's own SO entry. That being said, there is a somewhat similar existing SO question which may give you some insight here: [Difference between Grunt, NPM and Bower ( package.json vs bower.json )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21198977/difference-between-grunt-npm-and-bower-package-json-vs-bower-json)

2: There is an excellent free online course available from Microsoft which covers this. Check out Microsoft Virtual Academy, and look for the course named "**Building Responsive UI with Bootstrap**". You'll learn about Web Essentials, working with Visual Studio and much, much more.

3: See the very detailed Answer from this SO on how to implement a theme in an MVC 5 project: [Is there a walkthrough for implementing a theme from bootswatch or wrapbootstrap in an MVC 5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839351/is-there-a-walkthrough-for-implementing-a-theme-from-bootswatch-or-wrapbootstrap)