# How to implement the Gentelella Bootstrap Admin theme in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm starting now with web development in Visual Studio. I have already understood MVC, I have some knowledge of HTML and I started to study the bootstrap.
Then, I discovered the beautiful template *Free Bootstrap 3 Admin Template* on the web, which has an example online here: https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/index.html

I downloaded the files like `custom.css` and `custom.min.css` as they are shown in the following image:

[image: Image of downloaded files]

But now I don't know how to put it in my project, so I created a new clean project in Visual Studio Community 2015. I did some tests, and I created some controllers and views.

How can I change the default bootstrap theme that came with ASP.NET MVC project to the downloaded one?

I imagine I should replace the `_Layout` in the shared folder. But what else should I bring?

I do not want all those example pages, etc. Just Bootstrap and the base layout to create my view's.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement a theme from bootswatch or wrapbootstrap in an MVC 5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839351/how-can-i-implement-a-theme-from-bootswatch-or-wrapbootstrap-in-an-mvc-5-project)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found everything I needed from a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOLXdGbZ96c), entitled ***"Plantilla Bootstrap en Proyecto ASP.NET MVC"*** *(obviously in Spanish)*.

There are many steps:

1. Adding files to the project
2. setting the _Layout
3. set scripts references
4. bundles
5. Etc.

Ultimately, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

step one 
Create a MVC project Default template in visual studio 
Step Two 
Delete All cshtml in view folder expect shared folder 
you must be detrmine wthich part of  your page repeatly in all pages that is  your layout  and you can put html tag like header menu and footer in  /views/shared/_layout.cshtml   and write renderbody in part of layout  to see default login homepage or etc 
 finaly 
all css and java script folder  paste in your project and in layout   change target to available js and css resource

[Learn about mvc Layout](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/layout-view-in-asp.net-mvc)

[Understand Css And JavaScript embed from bundle](https://zoompf.com/blog/2015/01/automatically-optimize-css-javascript-asp-net/)