# Bootstrap template is not working in MVC application

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use free `Bootstrap template` from https://bootswatch.com/superhero/[Bootstrap](https://bootswatch.com/superhero/)
[Bootstrap](https://bootswatch.com/superhero/). I copied `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` from this site and pasted into my application but my application is not showing `navbar` like this template. 
please find the attached screenshot from this site and my home page.

From this site:
[image]

from my application:

[image]

My `_Layout.cs`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

My `BundleConfig.cs`:

```
 public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
    "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I implement a theme from bootswatch or wrapbootstrap in an MVC 5 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839351/how-can-i-implement-a-theme-from-bootswatch-or-wrapbootstrap-in-an-mvc-5-project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably not using the same Bootstrap version as the one being used for the Bootswatch theme. I had the same problem and opened an issue on Github, where Thomas Park gave me the following answer:

> Yup, just make sure you're on the same version as the Bootstrap being used. Right now v4 is on bootswatch.com, but you can grab older versions at https://bootswatch.com/3/ and https://bootswatch.com/2/

So, try updating your Bootstrap version **OR** using a previous version of the Bootswatch theme you want (from the links above).

Source: https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/issues/784

Answer (score 0):

In my _Layout.cshtml file, I have given the Scripts and Styles like this, together, on the head section:

```html
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Custom")
</head>
```

In your Bundle Config file, I don't think you need two separate statements to include the same bootstrap.css file.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using bundles.config and render scripts.Just download the bootstrap.min.css file and copy it into one of the folders in your MVC project. In the _layout.cshtml file,drag and drop that css file inside the  tag. It must work. Try it.