# Change default login page UI in asp.net

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, themes

I'm working on asp.net mvc5 project where i want to change the default theme of my login page, any idea how can  do this.
[image: this is the deafult ui which i want to change with some eye catching theme.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839351/how-can-i-implement-a-theme-from-bootswatch-or-wrapbootstrap-in-an-mvc-5-project check this link you will get some idea

Comment: I already read this but this is not what i'm looking.. i just  want to change the default theme of view of login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have view of login page or partial view. Try to find it in "View" folder in MVC project. So, probably, you use bundle for link css and js files. You can find configuration of bundles in `App_Start\BundleConfig.cs` file. In file `Application_Start` you register these css files:

```
ublic class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
   protected void Application_Start()
   {
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
   } 
}
```

So, you should understand what css file is responsible for styles in login page and change this file for your purpose.

I have noticed you use bootstrap styles. If you do not like this theme you can desable bootstrap styles, just remove bundle with bootstrap.css. Like this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
            "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
            "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Change to this:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
            "~/Content/site.css"));
```