# Issue with basic use of bootswatch in a new VS2019 MVC app

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bootswatch

I created a new MVC application in VS2019 using .NET 4.7.2 and MVC 5. The template renders fine.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6XfF.jpg

But... when I have downloaded the Bootswatch Lumen theme and then updated the CSS file referenced in the App_Start/BundleConfig.cs file and then rebuild and refresh, the menu at the top renders as the Application Title with an empty button which expands the menu items.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmzNs.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKcJb.jpg

This is not what happens in the tutorials. The menu items remain as a menu bar at the top and it looks like a basic theme change only.

Apologies if this is an easy one (I hope it is!) I'm a veteran WebFormer of 12 years finally making the MVC jump.

Comment: For reference, this was the instruction set I followed.... 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839351/how-can-i-implement-a-theme-from-bootswatch-or-wrapbootstrap-in-an-mvc-5-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC 5 template has bootstrap 3 included. Botswatch files are not bootstrap 4.